# Retrieving values from a table using ids

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Hi I have a teams table and then a fixture model:

```
 class Fixture < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :away_score, :away_team_id, :home_score, :home_team_id, :result, :week
 belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => 'Team'
 belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => 'Team'
end
```

Then I have a program to generate fixtures based on their team ids, but I am unsure where to add this in my rails app, I am trying to show the fixtures in a view based on 20 teams I already created but not sure how? So my output will be home team team_name with id 1 and away team team_name with id 2 for fixture 1 etc...

```
teams = Array(1..20)
fixed_team = teams.shift   #The fixed competitor described in the algorithm
teams.length.times do |i|

   #Create the two groups listed in the algorithm
   teams = teams.rotate
   week_teams = teams.dup.unshift(fixed_team) 
   first_group, second_group = week_teams.each_slice(week_teams.length/2).to_a
   second_group.reverse!
   weeks_pairings = first_group.zip(second_group)

   #Output the week's pairings
   puts "Week #{i + 1}: #{weeks_pairings}"
end 

#Output:
#=> Week 1: [[1, 2], [3, 20], [4, 19], [5, 18], [6, 17], [7, 16], [8, 15], [9, 14],             [10, 13], [11, 12]]
#=> Week 2: [[1, 3], [4, 2], [5, 20], [6, 19], [7, 18], [8, 17], [9, 16], [10, 15],   [11, 14], [12, 13]]
#=> etc
```

Comment: What do you need here exactly? How to output it in the view?

Comment: I still don't get what the above code is supposed to achieve...

Comment: I have a teams model with a list of teams, with id and team_name, my output is to generate the fixtures, so in my application I want to be able to see team[i]_name vs team[i]_name for each pair in the code output of the code above.

Comment: My aim is to create the fixtures for a round robin league. Each team plays eachother team once, and a team can only play once each week

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have 20 Teams entries (having an attribute `name`) in your DB (or more):

```
teams = Team.first(20)
fixed_team = teams.shift   #The fixed competitor described in the algorithm
teams.length.times do |i|

   #Create the two groups listed in the algorithm
   teams = teams.rotate
   week_teams = teams.dup.unshift(fixed_team) 
   first_group, second_group = week_teams.each_slice(week_teams.length/2).to_a
   second_group.reverse!
   weeks_pairings = first_group.zip(second_group)

   puts "Week #{i+1}: "
   weeks_pairings.each do |pair_of_teams|
     puts "#{pair_of_teams[0].name} vs. #{pair_of_teams[1].name}"
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the logic of your algorithm in your Fixture model; modularize it in a static method like

```
def self.show_fixtures
   #add algo here
end
```

But you have to modify the code to return an array or some other data structure.
Now you can do

```
Fixture.show_fixtures
```

Wherever - in any view, in controllers etc. to obtain the matchups.

You can also define a dedicated view for showing fixtures. First, add an action in the FixtureController

```
def show_fixtures
  @list = Fixture.show_fixtures
end
```

Then, add the view /views/fixture/show_fixtures.html.your_extension
In the view, your can iterate the @list array and render a partial for each matchup in the fixture.

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting what your code doing but as you said in comments I suggest you to do this.

Add this method in **Fixture**. Call **Fixture.create_fixture**

```
def self.create_fixture
  weeks_pairings = []
  teams = Team.all.map(&:name)
  fixed_team = teams.shift   #The fixed competitor described in the algorithm
  teams.length.times do |i|
    #Create the two groups listed in the algorithm
    teams = teams.rotate
    week_teams = teams.dup.unshift(fixed_team) 
    first_group, second_group = week_teams.each_slice(week_teams.length/2).to_a
    second_group.reverse!
    weeks_pairings << first_group.zip(second_group)
  end
    weeks_pairings #You can use this in view
end
```

In view:

```
 <% Fixture.create_fixture.each_with_index do |week, games_list| %>
   <%= "<h3> Week #{week+1} </h3>" %>
   <ul>
     <% games_list.each do |teams| %>
       <li><b><%= "#{teams.first} Vs #{teams.last}" %></li>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Is there a way I could assign the teams to home_team and away_team getting the first value in the pair as the home team and second value as away team without just printing them all as one

Comment: Do u want home_team Vs away_team ?

Comment: Yeah, at the moment I have a basic view and can create fixtures manually, my fixtures view shows 5 things home_team, away_team, home_score, away_score, result. So first id of each pair needs to be home_team and second away_team if you understand?